# Dealing with duplicated data in MPEG2-TS

Tags: udp, vlc, duplicate-data, mpeg2-ts

I'm using a setup in which I receive duplicated datagrams using UDP-based video streaming with VLC. I wanted to know if there's some field in MPEG-TS (ISO/IEC 13818-1) which I can use for detecting duplicated data and therefore discard it until it reaches the aplication layer.

The problem is that duplicated frames reach the top of the TCP/IP (Application Layer) stack and consequently create conflict with streaming. Continuity Counters (CC) of duplicated data are the same therefore the receiver thinks that there's a gap and skips.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, I can rely on the RTP protocol which use sequence numbers and timestamp.